# MySQL multiple values join to one table - better query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

is possible solve this task better way?

I have two mysql tables.

```
1) z_import_kategorie
id - kategorieHOME - kategoriePP - kategorieP
1  - 2             - 3          -  5
2  - 2             - 4          -  8
3  - 2             - 6          -  7

2) tm_category_lang
id_category - name - lang_id
2           - HOME - 1
2           - Uvod - 2
3           - Bikes - 1
3           - Kola - 2
4           - Windows - 1
4           - Okna - 2
5           - Cars - 1
5           - Auta - 2
6           - Wheels - 1
6           - Disky - 2
7           - Lights - 1
7           - Svetla - 2
8           - Doors - 1
8           - Dvere - 2
```

**I need join kategorieHOME, kategoriePP and kategorieP from table z_import_kategorie to category name from table tm_category_lang in single query.**

My query for this is:

```
SELECT z.*,k1.name AS katHOME,k2.name AS katPP,k3.name AS katP 
FROM z_import_kategorie AS z 
LEFT JOIN tm_category_lang AS k1 ON(k1.id_category = z.kategorieHOME) 
LEFT JOIN tm_category_lang AS k2 ON(k2.id_category = z.kategoriePP) 
LEFT JOIN tm_category_lang AS k3 ON(k3.id_category = z.kategorieP) 
GROUP BY z.id 
ORDER BY z.id ASC

RESULT of query is:

1 - HOME - Bikes - Cars
2 - HOME - Windows - Doors
3 - HOME - Wheels - Lights
```

Is possible design this query better? My query is working but I dont think that is good.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the point of groupping, if you don't use aggreagation operations?

Comment: There's no simpler way to write this. This is the correct way, except you don't need `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use **GROUP BY** in your query  to fetch the category names so remove it then your query will work.

Try this:

```
SELECT z.*, k1.name AS katHOME, k2.name AS katPP, k3.name AS katP 
FROM z_import_kategorie AS z 
LEFT JOIN tm_category_lang AS k1 ON k1.id_category = z.kategorieHOME AND k1.lang_id = 1
LEFT JOIN tm_category_lang AS k2 ON k2.id_category = z.kategoriePP AND k2.lang_id = 1
LEFT JOIN tm_category_lang AS k3 ON k3.id_category = z.kategorieP AND k3.lang_id = 1
ORDER BY z.id ASC
```

Comment: I need GROUP BY because for every category name (same category_id) exist names in two languages and result is duplicated by numbers of join from second table.

Comment: I think that your solution is better. Thank you :)

Comment: @David You're most welcome... If you find the proper answer then you can accept that answer.